# Get the text of an li element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<ul class="leftbutton" >
    <li id="menu-selected">Sample 1</li>
    <li>Sample 2</li>
    <li>Sample 3</li>
    <li>Sample 4</li>
    <li>Sample 5</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the text of the li item which the id="menu-selected".
Right now I am doing something like

```
document.getElementById('menu_selected').childNodes.item(0).nodeValue
```

Is there any simpler way of doing the same?

Comment: what if I want to get the text contained in all li elements...not just a specific one

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your case:

```
document.getElementById('menu_selected').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have HTML inside the LI elements and you only want to get the text, you need [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899(VS.85).aspx) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent).

```
var liEl = document.getElementById('menu_selected');
var txt = liEl["innerText" in liEl ? "innerText" : "textContent"];
```

To avoid using this conditional statement every time, you could just declare a global variable:

```
var textContentProp = "innerText" in document.body ? "innerText" : "textContent";
function getText()
{
    return document.getElementById('menu_selected')[textContentProp];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can use jQuery it boils down to

```
var text = $('#menu_selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.getElementById('menu_selected').text`

Comment: It should be `textContent` in FF and `text` in IE

Comment: @Amarghosh: It's `innerText` in IE, `text` only applies to a few elements.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how to do this for a broader sense instead of selecting by ID and came across this.

```js
const listItemTextContent = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li"))

const listItemTextArray = 
    listItemTextContent.map(itemText => itemText.firstChild.data)

console.log(listItemTextArray);
```

or you can use a condensed/chained alternative!

```js
const listItemTextContent = 
    Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll("li"))
        .map(itemText => itemText.firstChild.data)

console.log(listItemTextContent)
```

I hope this helps somebody!